# Replace SymPy sp.Symbol with ReferenceFrame vector

Tags: python, sympy

I'm having trouble subbing *Symbols* for *Vectors* with the *subs* function in SymPy. Below is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
N = ReferenceFrame('N')
zhat, Q, p = sp.symbols('\\hat{\\mathbf{z}} Q p')
expr = 4*Q*zhat/p
old = zhat
new = N.z
expr.subs(old, new)
```

I believe it necessary, given the context of this problem, to state that I require the initial expression *expr* to be comprised entirely of *Symbols* and to have type *Mul* before the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution for the exact above problem, but a very similar one:

```
N = CoordSys3D('N')
zhat, Q, p = sp.symbols('\\hat{\\mathbf{z}} Q p')
expr = 4*Q*zhat/p
old = zhat
new = N.k
expr.subs(old, new)
```

Using *CoordSys3D* instead of *ReferenceFrame* allows for substitution.